# golang: convert 16-byte uuid into 32 bytes

Tags: go

I'm trying to save a uuid as a Memo field on a Stellar transaction.  The memo field will take a string of 28 bytes or less; (as a string, a uuid is 36 bytes, so that won't work).  It can also take a hash of 32 bytes.  As bytes a uuid is 16 bytes.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to convert my uuid into a byte type that is 32 bytes?

Comment: You have a 16-bytes uuid, and you want to create a 32-bytes hash? Double the uuid and you have a perfect 32-bytes hash.

Comment: Or leave the remaining 16 bytes zero - same uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: Does it take a formatted hash? Then 32 hash characters correspond to 16 raw bytes exactly. Or you could Base64-encode it, then you'll have 24 human-readable characters.

Comment: @rustyx , that's pretty good.  do you want to respond with `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(uuid.Bytes())` and i'll upvote/accept it?